# How can I get code coverage for dart runtime?

Tags: flutter, dart, runtime, code-coverage

Briefly: Can anyone tell me how to know if the dart code has been invoked or how to mark it as hits and misses.

We can get test coverage by 'flutter test --coverage'. But this rely on test.dart file, I mean we have to write test.dart file for the file and function we care about. If we can collect the coverage info when dart is running, it will be easier for us to know which code lines has been invoked. And I think it will be friendly for developers.

I have searched dart-lang/sdk, only know that 'flutter test --coverage' gets reports by invokeRpcRaw('getSourceReport'...), but I have no idea how to get reports for dart runtime.

If runtime dose not work, can I do something when compile?

Comment: https://pub.dev/packages/test_coverage makes this easy or in recent Dart versions `dart test --coverage="coverage_out_dir"`

Answer (score 2):

On Mac

```
brew install lcov
```

Or use ubuntu or windows alternatives for this

then

```
flutter test --coverage
genhtml coverage/icov.info -o coverage/html
open coverage/html
```

Comment: Actually I know this method. But this coverage is for unit test code coverage, I want to find a method to collect coverage for dart runtime code coverage.
Thank you all the same

Answer (score 1):

A straightforward solution that worked for me:

1. **Install Coverage:**

   ```bash
   dart pub global activate coverage
   ```
2. After activating coverage, use the following command to automatically generate the `lcov.info` file:

   ```bash
   dart pub global run coverage:test_with_coverage
   ```

Here is my source [Dart Coverage GitHub repository](https://github.com/dart-lang/coverage) for more details.

Comment: If you only need this for one project, you can just add `coverage: ^1.7.2` to dev_dependencies in pubspec.yaml and then run `dart run coverage:test_with_coverage`

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/dart-lang/coverage  may help you

1. flutter pub global activate coverage
2. flutter run (you can use -d to select device)
3. flutter pub global run coverage:collect_coverage --uri=http://... -o coverage.json --resume-isolates
4. flutter pub global run coverage:format_coverage --packages=./.packages --report-on lib --in coverage.json --out lcov.info --lcov

I have try this and finally get the lcov.info in runtime, good luck